# WebDriver to close popup window after certain time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a `Selenium WebDriver` based test, which fill a form and send it for processing. During time period of processing a window is opened. Sometimes processing fails, but this window is not closed, so we can't get result. Purpose of this test is to get the result. I try to set a timeout for this window, so it should be closed after a predefined time (I set it to 10 seconds now.) by `WebDriver` and form should be resent. I use following code.

```
WebElement webElement;
try {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(sendButton).click();
    webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("button-resultdown")));
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    webElement = null;
} finally {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
if (webElement == null) {
    driver.findElement(popUpClose).click();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    driver.findElement(sendButton).click();
}
```

Popup window is not closed automatically after 10 seconds. I checked element locators, those are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to not use explicit and implicit waits in same time, find more details [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12583/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-implicit-wait-in-selenium-webdriver-should-one-use).
For popup close you can try to click using JavaScript or wait until `popUpClose` will be clickable.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

driver.findElement(sendButton).click();

List<WebElement> elements = waitElements(driver, 5, By.className("button-resultdown"));
if (elements.size() == 0){
    List<WebElement> popUpCloseButtons = driver.findElements(popUpClose);
    System.out.println("Popup Close Buttons size: " + popUpCloseButtons.size());
    if (popUpCloseButtons.size() > 0)
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", popUpCloseButtons.get(popUpCloseButtons.size() - 1));
        //popUpCloseButtons.get(popUpCloseButtons.size() - 1).click();
}
```

And custom wait method:

```
public List<WebElement> waitElements(WebDriver driver, int timeout, By locator) throws InterruptedException {
    List<WebElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++) {
        elements = driver.findElements(locator);
        if (elements.size() > 0)
            break;

        System.out.println("Not!");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how could I define a "timeout" value, when window should be closed by WebDriver?

Comment: I should wait for a predefined time and after that click close button and after that waiting for window to disappear. So this code missed first step, waiting for a predefined time(10 seconds). Button is clickable when page is loaded, so it is not a good condition.

Comment: Predefined time you can set in in `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);`.  `if (elements == null)` if there's no result then click on close button. And then wait until `invisibilityOfElementLocated` wait predefined time you set for the explicit wait. If you want click until popup will be closed you can put it in a loop also

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work, hasn't any effect. I tried to use `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated` too, but I got `TimeoutException` after 10 seconds and popup is still open.

Comment: Sure, I checked it manually. I already tried that code to close window after 3 seconds waiting time: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9SwFPGsynC/ (spinner element is displayed during loading)

Comment: Check updated code. Also check if there're more than one popUpClose button in the DOM

Comment: That is working! You are right, xpath of button is changing during process.